# Read Octal characters when reading csv files in R

Tags: r, macos, csv, character-encoding, octal

I'm trying to read a csv file in R and its header contains spanish characters (such as "ó").
When I read it as `read.csv("1cona.csv")`, special characters (ó) are displayed as dots. (i.e. producci.n instead of producción).

I tried using `read.csv("1cona.csv",check.names = F)` and R is reading the csv header as `Producci\363n`. I understand that is a Octal character, however, I am not sure how to read it correctly. I am using OS X (not sure if that is the problem).

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the file encoding Or just open the text file in notepad and save as `UTF-8`